# CSS three images fade-in animation duration

Tags: html, css, animation

I am confused by the CSS fade-in animation for multiple images. I thought I had found a solution with John Bacon's codepen https://codepen.io/johnbacon/pen/wgYOXW, but I cannot figure out how to use three pictures instead of four. I want each of my three images to display for 30 seconds before fading to the next image, and I cannot have a period when there is no image showing.

**HTML**

```
enter code here
<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 1" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 2" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 3" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/450x280?text=Image 4" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-container {
position: relative;

img {
position: absolute;
animation-name: multiple-image-crossfade;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 8s;
&:nth-of-type(1) {
animation-delay: 6s;
}
&:nth-of-type(2) {
animation-delay: 4s;
}
&:nth-of-type(3) {
animation-delay: 2s;
}
&:nth-of-type(4) {
animation-delay: 0;
}
}
}

@keyframes multiple-image-crossfade {
0% {
opacity:1;
}
17% {
opacity:1;
}
25% {
opacity:0;
}
92% {
opacity:0;
}
100% {
opacity:1;
}
}
```

I do not have SASS available so I tried to convert this to CSS like so:

```
    .image-container {
    height: 280px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: multiple-image-crossfade;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 120s;
    }
    .image-container img .image-container:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 90s;
    }
    .image-container img .image-container:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 60s;
    }
    .image-container img .image-container:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 30s;
    }
   .image-container img .image-container:nth-of-type(4) {
   animation-delay: 0s;
   }

   @keyframes multiple-image-crossfade {
   0% {
   opacity: 1;
   }
   17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  92% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  }
```

This doesn't work on my test site here: https://rbbt.net/sds-fcm/sds-tyler/index.htm
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total animation time calculated by : **30s * 4 = 120s**   // 4 images having 30s.

- First image start with 0s (0s - 30s)
- Second image start with 30s (30s - 60s)
- Third image start with 60s (60s - 90s)
- Fourth image start with 90s (90s - 120s)

that is,

In **SCSS**

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  
  img {
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: multiple-image-crossfade;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 120s;
    &:nth-of-type(1) {
      animation-delay: 90s;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2) {
      animation-delay: 60s;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(3) {
      animation-delay: 30s;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(4) {
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }
  }
}
```

In **CSS**

```
.image-container {position: relative;}
.image-container img{
   position: absolute;
   animation-name: multiple-image-crossfade;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-duration: 120s;
}
.image-container img:nth-of-type(1) {
   animation-delay: 90s;
}
.image-container img:nth-of-type(2) {
   animation-delay: 60s;
}
.image-container img:nth-of-type(3) {
   animation-delay: 30s;
}
.image-container img:nth-of-type(4) {
   animation-delay: 0s;
}
```

Codepen Demo in **SCSS**: https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/MWyjrOJ

Codepen Demo in **CSS**: https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/ExKNBQx

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the timing issue. I can create a fourth image if I must, but my client asked for me to use three pictures that he supplied. How does the @keyframes element relate to the number of images? What would I need to change to use three photos instead of four?

Comment: I attempted to change the code from a SASS iteration to CSS like so:

Comment: Are you want it's css ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the SASS converter but something is wrong. I do not know enough about the animations to see the problem so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I added css demo in here, I added every image with 3s instead of 30s. for know the animation delay understand.

Comment: Try this :) , if any doubt comment here. (y) @Pelinor bro

Comment: That did it (ExKNBQx pen). Thank you for the help, the CodePen also helped me understand how the CSS animations work.